# Electron with Reactjs execFile error when packing the app

Tags: reactjs, electron, child-process

I use `var child = require("child_process").execFile;` to run an external .exe file. When i run the app in debug mode everything runs smoothly. When i build and pack the application then it throws the following error.
**Uncaught TypeError: (0 , a(...).execFile) is not a function**

My code:

```
var path = require("path");

export function silentPrintPDF(htmlString) {
  var child = require("child_process").execFile;
  var executablePath = path.join(
    __dirname,
    "extraResources",
    "ElectronPrinter.exe"
  );
  var parameters = [htmlString];

  child(executablePath, parameters, function(err, data) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data.toString());
  });
}
```

I pack the app with the following command:
**"electron:pack": "yarn build && electron-builder build -w"**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I did some lazy searching around and some suggestions say to use window.require instead of just require. Apparently it gets confused between electron's and browserify's require function. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300

Comment: Yes that was it. I really had no clue so I couldn't find anything. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, the answer ended up being to use `window.require` to prevent it getting confused between Electoron's require and Browserify's require.

[Source](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300)